# SQL Update Where Statement

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table of images with a corresponding listing_id and position.

image_name, listing_id, position

- There can be multiple images per listing_id.
- Each image has an integer position representing the display order

If a listing_id does not have an image in position 1, I'd like to take the lowest position for that listing_id and set it to position 1.

Something like:

```
update media_table set position = 1 where ...
```

Comment: Is `1` the lowest possible position or is it possible to have a `0` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a **syntax fix by @ypercube**, the query now works for MySQL:

```
UPDATE media_table m
JOIN (
    SELECT listing_id, min(position) AS position
    FROM   media_table
    GROUP  BY listing_id
    HAVING min(position) > 1
    ) x ON (m.listing_id, m.position) = (x.listing_id, x.position)
SET    m.position = 1;
```

Explanation:

In the subquery find all `linsting_id` where the minimum `position` is greater than 1. Use these findings to update the rows right away. I assume `(listing_id, position)` is unique.

[See working demo for MySQL.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/087b2/1)

Comment: The logic is 100% sound but I'm not sure this works (in MySQL's twisted `UPDATE` syntax).

Comment: @ypercube: Right, that syntax does not work with MySQL. Missed the tag. I provided an alternative solution that should work.

Comment: @ypercube: I must have misread the manual, as your alternative syntax clearly works. Selecting from a subquery and *then* updating an involved table is no problem then ...

Comment: Yeah, the problems with Update are related with the table (to be updated) appearing in a `WHERE` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE media_table
SET position=(SELECT MIN(position) FROM media_table)
WHERE listing_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Do you want something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
update images i1,
( select i1.image_name, i1.listing_id from images i1
  left join images i2
  on i1.listing_id = i2.listing_id and i1.position > i2.position
  where i2.position is null and i1.position != 1
) f
set position = 1
where i1.image_name = f.image_name and i1.listing_id = f.listing_id;
```

This assumes you can identify a record by `image_name, listing_id`. If you can do so by `image_name` then the query would be simpler as you can remove the `listing_id` comparison and selection.